# How can I access two models connected by a foreignkey for a DetailView and a CreateView?

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-views, django-2.2

I am building a wiki and need to save every revision made for each wikipage. This means that i need a new revision tabel for every wikipage created.

When presenting each wikipage template with DetailView i need to access Wikipage.title, the latest revision and its Revision.content, Revision.author, Revision.last_edit and Revision.comment. I have been able to access the title, by setting "model=Wikipage" and revision, by setting "model=Revision" but not both at the same time.

**models.py**

```
class Wikipage(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField('Created', auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Wikipages"


class Revision(models.Model):
    wikipage = models.ForeignKey(Wikipage, null=True, 
               on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='revision')
    content = models.TextField('Content')
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, 
             on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    last_edit = models.DateTimeField('Last edit', auto_now=True)
    comment = models.TextField('Comment', blank=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Revision'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Revisions'
        ordering = ['-last_edit']
        get_latest_by = ['last_edit']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.content
```

I wanted to use the DetailView and CreateView that comes with django, but I have not succeeded in accessing specific data from both tables.
I have gotten the ListView to work correctly, but that only needs the title from Wikipage, and nothing from Revision.

Comment: You need to be a bit more specific. What data do you need to access, in what form, what did you try and where did you have problems?

Comment: When presenting each wikipage template with DetailView i need to access Wikipage.title, the latest revision and its Revision.content, Revision.author, Revision.last_edit and Revision.comment.

I have been able to access the title, by setting "model=Wikipage" and revision, by setting "model=Revision" but not both at the same time.

Also tried messing around with .objects.filter(...) without any luck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access the latest revision for a wikipage via `wikipage.revision.latest()`, since you correctly defined `get_latest_by` on the Revision model.  You can do that directly in the template:

```
{% with wikipage.revision.latest as revision %}
  {{ revision.last_edit }}
  {{ revision.comment }}
{% endwith %}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I am not getting any values in the template when calling revision.last_edit, revision.comment or revision.content.
I am correctly defining the DetailView Class with only " model=Wikipage " as content in the class?

Comment: To clarify: I have no problems accessing the wikipage.title
Only the content inside the Revision table. The simply appear as nothing even though I have put dummy data in through the admin page

Comment: Did you use that `with` statement? What if you do just `{{ revision }}` inside the with block? What does just `{{ wikipage.revision.all }}` without the block show? And how exactly are you accessing the wikipage title?

Comment: After some more testing I got the code to work with your first answer. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

On the `DetailView` you can access all the revisions using `wikipage.revision` where wikipage is the object of the `DetailView` and you could query the revisions to get the latest one.

I would recommend also this change

```
wikipage = models.ForeignKey(Wikipage, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='revision')
```

to be

```
wikipage = models.ForeignKey(Wikipage, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='revisions')
```